# R Chunk Code within Enumeration Environment with knitr in LyX

Tags: lyx, enumerate, sweave, knitr

I need `R Chunk Code` within `Enumeration Environment` in `Rnw` file. The following `.Rnw` document works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\\
<<boring-random>>=
1:4
@
\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\item The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But when I import the same file to `LyX`, the `R Chunk Code` delimiter `@` combines with text (See image below). I would highly appreciate if you guide me how to put `R Chunk Code` within `Enumeration Environment` in `LyX` using `LyX` built-in `Enumeration Environment`. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about LyX, but have you read [Using `knitr` with LyX](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/)? I assume that might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've "kind of" run into a LyX bug/feature enhancement http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8875

The workaround is simple: add an empty line at the end of your ERT box, after "@".

I say "kind of" above because once that ticket is fixed (possibly in 2.2.0 version which won't be out for a while), I'm not sure we will activate that option for ERT. It will be activated for the Chunk inset, which if you're using LyX 2.1.1 you can get by going to Insert > Custom Insets > Chunk. It's a matter of preference whether to use that inset or ERT. Note that the knitr author, also a LyX user, prefers to use ERT. I prefer to use the Chunk inset.

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty for your nice answer. Could you guide me how to add an empty line at the end of `ERT` box, after `@`. Thanks

Comment: Let's see if @Yihui has any solution.

Comment: @MYaseen208 sure, put your cursor just to the right of `@` (but still inside the ERT box). Then press <Return> on your computer.

Comment: @MYaseen208 No, I do not have a different solution. I always use what Scott provided here.

Comment: @YihuiXie I am currently using LyX version 2.3.5.2 and ran into the same problem even after the fix that is suggested here. Can you help me out?

Comment: @DebarthaPaul please open a new question and please post a minimal working example. See here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. In your new question, please reference this question.

Comment: @scottkosty I found a fix, I should add an empty line at the beginning of the `ERT` box, before `<<>>=`, which I had not done previously

Comment: @DebarthaPaul glad to hear!